# Bluetooth Low Energy in .Net (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth-lowenergy, uwp

is it possible to use bluetooth low energy (ble) with .Net (C#) in an console app? For Example like with windows.devices.bluetooth in uwp apps.

I would just do it in uwp, but I need vJoy which is designed for .Net and the MbientLab Metawear C hardware as sensor with ble.

Comment: Yeap, easy.  [Bluetooth Framework .NET Edition](https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use C# APIs in C# Desktop applications! I have a [sample here in GitHub](https://github.com/CarterAppleton/Win10Win32Bluetooth).

In general, to get access to the C# APIS, add two references to your project:

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll

Note that the #2 version depends on the version of .Net that you're using.

> Background tasks will not be supported, but all other Bluetooth C#
>   features should be there.

Comment: What are background tasks? Is it possible to connect and communicate with BLE devices? The sample only shows how to receive advertisements.

Comment: Ya, but is there a cross platform solution?  https://github.com/nexussays/BLE.net  That covers a couple additional platforms, but not linux