# Is there a way use Bluetooth LE libraries C# in Windows 10 to communicate with sensors or micro-controllers?

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I spent some time looking for ways to exchange data from a micro-controller [Bluno Beetle](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1259.html) from DFRobots that uses Bluetooth LE and a desktop application written in C#. DFRobots actually has a [code](https://github.com/DFRobot/BlunoBasicDemo) (in Java Android), where they use GATT profiles to exchange data from/to the micro-controller and an Android Phone. I tested this app myself and it works perfectly. I would like to have a similar application written in C# running on a Desktop. I recently bought a BLE [dongle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06WV9XJCR) (the cheapest option I found on Amazon) which I can pair successfully.

So far, I found solutions that involve using UWP, being one of those an example for exchanging data between a [Windows Phone and a Heart Rate monitor](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Generic-5a99ef95), and very little documentation on how to accomplish that for Desktop applications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333179/is-there-any-way-to-use-bluetooth-le-from-a-c-sharp-desktop-app-in-windows-10) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818576/bluetooth-low-energy-in-net-c), that involve using System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime but no other information about how to connect to a device or listen to what is being broadcast.

Do any of you guys know if it is really possible to accomplish that? And if so, are you aware of a tutorial I could use to help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> but no other information about how to connect to a device or listen to what is being broadcast

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE) is an official and complete BLE client/server sample which you can use as a starting point

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! With this example, I am able to pair my BLE dongle to the micro-controller, connect to it and list the services and characteristics, and even read/send data to the micro-controller. However, I am having problems to subscribe to one of the characteristics (even though it has the notify and write flags), and when I try to read the data from the characteristic, it returns values different than those that I streaming from the micro-controller. But I guess I'll have to figure it out myself. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DennisCunha can i integerate with BLE controller with windows form c sharp

Answer (score -1):

Look into the BTFramework library.  We have worked with it for years.  It took one afternoon to establish good communication with an ioT device this week.  We are using C# NET, by the way.  Their libraries have worked well on all platforms from the latest versions of Windows 10 all the way back to barely-functioning XP machines, skipping Vista of course.
As to the dongles you can buy... we support a commercial product using those dongles, and found their marketing claims don't always support their performance.  Some work fine for a day, then fail, then work again. And one large batch from one vendor may work fine, but a batch purchased months later may have a high failure rate when you are pushing the envelope.