# Accessing Win10 API (Specifically BLE) from .NET app

Tags: windows, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a non-UWP .NET app and would like to use BLE. The only support for BLE in windows comes from the UWP API.

My question is can I access the UWP API from my .NET app, and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not from UWP API. It's from WinRT API which you can access from any .NET app, and even from a normal C++ app as well.

See for example [Bluetooth Low Energy in .Net (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818576/bluetooth-low-energy-in-net-c).