# BLE Using WinRT: Access Denied When Executing "GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync()" for Write Characteristic

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy, winrt-component

Maybe someone can help me out because I have a really tricky situation with Bluetooth LE using WinRT on Windows 10 (like supposed here: [Bluetooth Low Energy in .Net (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818576/bluetooth-low-energy-in-net-c)).

I need BLE within a Win32 classic desktop application.
Our code is running in a 32 Bit frame application using the .NET runtime (v4.0.30319, .NET Framework 4.6.2). I was able to manage all the other issues (strong naming some NuGet assemblies (Shiny.BluetoothLE), running `BluetoothAdapter.GetRadioAsync()` in a 64 Bit COM surrogate DLL when running on 64 Bit Windows) but now I am totally stuck with this and here’s where:

The problem occurrs when executing `var result = await gattDeviceService.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(uuid, BluetoothCacheMode.Cached);` see here https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattdeviceservice.getcharacteristicsforuuidasync?view=winrt-20348.
When getting the read characteristics, the `result.Status` is `GattCommunicationStatus.Success` and the result contains the desired characteristic.
But of course I also need to get the write characteristic and I am ALWAYS getting `GattCommunicationStatus.AccessDenied`!
Because of that the result contains NO characteristic.

Has anybody a clue why is that? I really need help here because I am kinda lost right now…

I also tried to set `AccessPermission` via registry like supposed [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da3fdb-a0e1-4161-8af3-778b6839f4e1/bluetooth-bluetoothledevicefromidasync-does-not-complete-on-10015063?forum=wdk) but no luck at all…

PS: I use Windows 10 SDK Kit Build 20348 and like stated above it is a C# .NET Framework 4.6.2 project and all our assemblies are strong named because of using GAC. If I am missing anything don’t hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles over the same stupid issue...Here's the solution:

On Windows, using .NET Framework 4.6.1+ and the WinRT libraries inside a Non-UWP application, you can only call **ONCE** for getting the characteristics, no matter if you call for all at once via `gattDeviceService.GetCharacteristicsAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached)` or for a specific one via `gattDeviceService.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(uuid, BluetoothCacheMode.Cached)`.

Any subsequent calls will fail with `GattCommunicationStatus.AccessDenied`...
So my solution now is to retrieve all characteristics at once and filter them locally.

That did the trick! Anyways, this is so stupid...It wasted a lot of my time now!
As it seems, I also do not need to set any `AccessPermission` via registry.

PS: I will call out to you, if I stumble over another tricky situation, just to let you guyz know.

Answer (score 3):

I may have found a way to get around the problem.

**tl;dr**: **Dispose** both the **BluetoothLEDevice** and the **GattDeviceService** you get while connecting! The system thinks it is still in use!

In my case (using Windows 10, but not an UWP application, calling WinRT libs) this happens:
Only the first call gives me the attributes, then "Access Denied".
After some time a single call will give a valid answer again, but it's pretty rare (in one case after 52 seconds, in another 21 seconds).

In this case I will try to make a solution when everytime I'm asking for data, I will build the BLE from ground up (device detection, looking for correct device, getting attributes), get the data and then destroy everything, then do it again everytime I need data from a device.
This feels very wrong and could lead to more problems.
The reasoning behind this that the first time I collect information, everything is accessible.

In fact I did not need a total rebuild! I just needed to dispose both the BluetoothLEDevice and the GattDeviceService from my connection.
I got my device from

```
BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
```

And my service with

```
GattDeviceService service = await device.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(serviceUUID, BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
```

After I disposed them, a new call of connection (from BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id)) works again!

```
service.Dispose();
device.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very late for answer but for anyone having similar problem as mine can try this.

As [M.Hartner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71629360) Mentioned above, .NET lets you call only once for getting characteristics. In my case I was watching for devices that are connecting and disconnecting. When a device is reconnected, I was getting access denied as .NET was thinking there is still link between Bluetooth devices.
The correct way to solve this issue is by disposing the `GattDeviceService` when device is disconnected.
So every time `DeviceWatcher` notifies that device has been removed, I will dispose the 'GattDeviceService' of that device.

```
 private void DeviceWatcher_Removed(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate args);
 {
     var bleDevice= GetDeviceWithID(args.Id);
     bleDevice.gattDeviceService.Dispose();
 }
```

**In your case if you are requesting GATT characteristics multiple times in same session(i.e. Device is still in connected state) then better option as [you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71629360/9184864) in answer is to maintain a local copy of characteristics.**